# Multiple Application in single SSL 443 server NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have two application served in a single server `app1.domain.com` and `app2.domain.com`.

I want to proxy pass the request from `app1` to serve static file and `app2` to `proxy_pass` `localhost:8000`

I already have both SSL certificate using letsencrypt, how can I serve both apps using a single server?

I thought I can use different `server_name`. I read from [here](https://whatididtodowhatidid.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/subdomains-for-ports-on-same-ubuntu-server-with-nginx-reverse-proxy/): the article use multiple NGINX `server` with the same port 80. But when I try for the port 443 the test fails "duplicate listen options for..". Here is my current config

```
server {
    server_name app1.domain.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app1.domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app1.domain.com/privkey.pem; 

    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

server {
    server_name app2.domain.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app2.domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app2.domain.com/privkey.pem; 

    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000/;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host ~ "app1.domain.com|app2.domain.com") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name domain.id;
    return 404; 
}
```

And I thought maybe I could use `if ($host = domain)` inside the `location` but it fails too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, turns out I just have to remove the line 
`listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;`
and it works.

it's leftover from running NGINX certbot, I thought that was important

Comment: You can mark this as answered.